# Changing the font-size of the text box changes the margins

Tags: html, css

when I put a font-size: 9px on the text box, it gets it right, aligned above and below, but it is a very small font size.
but when putting a font-size: 15px it is a good font size but I enlarge the div up and down as you can see in the images:
font-size: 9px: https://postimg.cc/2L3dkwJN
font-size: 15px: https://postimg.cc/F1KVVrKC
How could i fix it?
This is my code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
    <title>TODO supply a title</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <LINK REL=StyleSheet HREF="css/bootstrap.css" TYPE="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="estilos_menu.css">
    <style>
        .icono
            {
                width:30px;/*tama�o del icono*/
                height:20px;
            }
    </style>
    </head>
<body>
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row " >
    <div class="col-sm-2 col-lg-2 bg-secondary my-auto" style="z-index:3;">
    <!--<div class="hamburguer">-->
<div class="row" style="margin-top:30px !important;margin-bottom:30px !important;">
<div class="col-5">   
    <div>
                            <ul class="nav">
                                    <li><img class="icono"  src="hamburguer.png">
                                            <ul>
                                                    <li><a href="">Tienda</a>
                                                            <ul>
                                                                <li><a href="">Ver todo</a></li>
                                                                    <li><a href="">Armarios</a></li>
                                                                    <li><a href="">Sillas</a></li>
                                                                    <li><a href="">Sillones</a></li>
                                                                    <li><a href="">Sofás</a></li>
                                                                    <li><a href="">Mesas</a></li>
                                                                    <li><a href="">Mesillas y cajoneras</a></li>
                                                                    <li><a href="">Lámparas</a></li>
                                                            </ul>
                                                    </li>
                                                    <li><a href="blog_principal.php">Blog</a>
                                            <ul>
                                                    <li><a href="minimalista.php">Estilo minimalista</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="nordico.php">Estilo nórdico</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="retro.php">Estilo retro</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="rustico.php">Estilo rústico</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="clasico.php">Estilo clásico</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="exteriores.php">Espacios exteriores</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="fusion_estilos.php">Fusión de estilos</a></li>                     
                                                    <!--</li>-->
                                            </ul>
                                    </li>
                                            </ul>
                                    </li>   
                            </ul>

                    </div>              

    </div> <!-- div col-->
        <div class="col-7">
        <a href="#">BOKDEKÓ</a>
        </div>
</div>
</div>
    <div class="col-sm-10 col-lg-5 bg-danger my-auto" >
    <div class="row" style="margin-top:30px !important;margin-bottom:30px !important;">

        <div class="col-2">    
        <a href ="#">Cuenta</a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-2">
        <a href ="#">Registrarse</a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-8">    
        Busca productos
        <input type=text name=buscar size='12' maxlength='15' value='' style="padding-top:1px;padding-bottom:1px;font-size:9px;">
        </div>
    </div>
    </div><!--div col-->
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-5 bg-info my-auto"><!--align-self-center-->
        <div class="row" style="margin-top:30px !important;margin-bottom:30px !important;">
            <div class="col-3 ">
            <a href="#">Mi lista</a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-3 bg-success">
            <a href ="#">Carrito</a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-6 bg-warning">
            <a href="#">Hola</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div> <!--div col-->
    </div> <!--div row-->
</div>
<script src="js/popper.min.js"  type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"  type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/utilidades.js"  type="text/javascript"></script>  
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your inline margin styles are what is causing this. The textbox is tall if the font size is bigger and then the margin pushes the height beyond where you'd like it.

Without heavily reworking what you have, you could remove those inline styles and just add a class to the parent row and use that to set a fixed height.

```css
.nav-section .row {
  height: 80px;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row nav-section">
    <div class="col-sm-2 col-lg-2 bg-secondary my-auto" style="z-index:3;">
      <!--<div class="hamburguer">-->
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-5">
          <div>
            <ul class="nav">
              <li><img class="icono" src="hamburguer.png"></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- div col-->
        <div class="col-7">
          <a href="#">BOKDEKÓ</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-10 col-lg-5 bg-danger my-auto">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-2">
          <a href="#">Cuenta</a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-2">
          <a href="#">Registrarse</a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-8">
          Busca productos
          <input type="text" name="buscar" size="12" maxlength="15" value="">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--div col-->
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-5 bg-info my-auto">
      <!--align-self-center-->
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-3 ">
          <a href="#">Mi lista</a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-3 bg-success">
          <a href="#">Carrito</a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-6 bg-warning">
          <a href="#">Hola</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--div col-->
  </div>
  <!--div row-->
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Difficult to tell since you did not accompany any of the actual css styles with your code, just HTML. I assume the issue could be that you did not specify heights of your div elements, and are just using padding. Since the div doesn't have a set height, it will be entirely dependent on the content inside of it, which is a no no. See the jsfiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/gxupa32z/) as an example. Also I recommend using "box-sizing: border-box;" to prevent any future issues with your margins and padding.

```
<div id="size-twelve">
<p>
Size 12
</p>
</div>
<div id="size-fifteen">
<p>
Size 15
</p>
</div>

#size-twelve {
  font-size: 12px;
  background-color: red;
  padding: 20px;
    width: 40%;
      display: inline-block;
    
}

#size-fifteen {
  font-size: 15px;
  background-color: green;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 40%;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Solution? Give your divs fixed heights in px. i.e 200px